# Query string parameter Or New Route In OsClass

Tags: php, content-management-system, osclass

I'm new in Os Class customization.
I wanna create a marketplace website. I have a problem. 
How to create route like `www.web.com/sell` or `www.web.com/buy` which the `buy` and `sell` parameter will use for category filter ?

Someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

The URL rewriting settings (permalinks) are located in your admin panel:

Settings > Permalinks

Here's a [video tutorial on how to enable permalinks on Osclass](https://osclass.org/tutorials/become-a-pro/how-to-enable-friendly-permalinks_68).

You can then have `http://yoursite.com/{CATEGORY_NAME}/`

Two small tips:

- Make sure the rewrite apache2 module is enabled.
- Make sure your vhost (if you have one) has a directive `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will try

Comment: hey @Hussard how about if i wanna add new item but add Category as a parameter example web.com/new/buy

Comment: Not sure if it works with category name but it should work with category id.